# How strong are vampires in The Vampire Diaries?

Tags: vampire, magical-creatures, the-vampire-diaries

What is the strength level of vampires in The Vampire Diaries universe? What feats of strengths have been shown?

Comment: i think we see someone punch through a wall, but i dont think you ever see anyone pick up a car even.

Answer (score 4):

The strength level of the vampires in the show is not always consistent, and also seems to vary depending on several factors (how old they are, how well-fed they are, etc.) But typically, they seem to have strength that's supernatural but not ridiculously so; perhaps 2-3 times what a good bodybuilder could manage.

To give you an idea how varying it is: in some cases, we have seen vampires break out of handcuffs or bust up large furniture. In other scenes, though, they've been successfully restrained using plain ropes. If anything, I think the werewolves are the brutes of the series: Tyler Lockwood needed to be locked up in a very heavy solid-metal room when he changed.

In combat, they are shown to be above average hand-to-hand fighters. They routinely snap people's necks with ease, and punch their fists through people's chests to rip out hearts/spines/etc. They can also manhandle average-sized human adults, including throwing them across the room.

They have never been shown to have ridiculous levels of strength: to my knowledge, they've never ripped a steel door off its hinges or stopped a moving car or lifted incredibly heavy objects.

Mostly, they rely on their speed and stamina to get them out of trouble.

Comment: their speed like, doesn't match their strength its kinda weird.

Comment: Muscle and muscle fiber used for speed and strength are different. A kick boxer and a marathon runner and sprinter all have different leg strengths

Answer (score 2):

TVD vampires don't really have strong "lifting" feats of strength or at least anything really definitive. What has been shown is that even newly made vampires like Caroline Forbes can easily lift an adult human off the ground with one hand and showing no strain whatsoever. She also kicked an adult male weighing 180lbs 10ft through the air and he would have gone further if he didn't hit a tree. Shortly after she was turned into a vampire Caroline Forbes was able to move a stone slab that was around 6ft tall x 3ft wide x 4-6in thick without straining herself.

In Season 1, Elena flipped her car and Damon mentioned moving the car to the side of the road, which suggests that pushing/dragging around 1-2 tons is doable.

Damon and Stefan have also shown being able to break solid chains without much effort.

One of the greater feat of strengths that I've seen is when Stefan jumped more than 50 feet vertically while carrying Elena. He did so with ease and didn't even bend his legs much.

There is another feat, though it is more of a durability feat than a strength one. I only include it because durability and strength are closely related. The body has to be tough enough to withstand the forces exerted by the person lifting or hitting something. Otherwise what would be the point if a vampire lifted a person or car and broke their arms doing so? Their bodies have to have a certain amount of toughness. When Elena was first turned into a vampire she jumped off of a 100 foot cliff. She landed crouched down, so her body absorbed a lot of the energy but she wasn't injured at all. No broken bones, torn muscles/ligaments or even a bruise. And she was a newly made vampire. Considering vampires get stronger as they get older, they will also get tougher.

Comment: The toughness bit doesn't make any sense when taking into consideration how easily vampires are damaged. They also do not have superspeed from muscle. If they did there would be supersonic shockwaves, G forces rendering normal people they carry into a red mist, holes in the pavement, etc. Their speed resembles mass effect speed. Warping spacetime. If their strength is tactile telekinesis then they are only tough when actively using their strength. It does go hand in hand with their telepathic abilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think they can't be more stronger than the witches. Because, As shown, the originals also came into existence by the witch.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Without qualifying how strong a witch is, this doesn't answer the question, even if you can justify that the vampires are not as strong as witches, which you haven't supported.

Answer (score -5):

**Strength/Striking Force:** Vampires here have been shown to hit so hard that they decapitate targets with their bare hands. See Damon beheading Kia. The strength they exude is so powerful that anything in their hand becomes a weapon. In Season 7 Ep.12, Damon Salvatore was shown throwing an envelope so hard that it beheaded a vampire and then embedded itself halfway into metal.

**Durability:** A day-old cancer vampire turned by Caroline Forbes was shown stabbing himself 8 times in the heart in an attempt to end his cancer pain, but all to no avail.

**Healing and Regeneration:** Damon and Enzo as Augustin Vampire Subjects were weakened below human levels with vervaine and given no food or water, yet had their organs like liver, kidneys, eyes etc. harvested for over 50 years.